# How can I insert the TimeStamp (current date and current time) into a datetime field of a Microsoft SQL server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, rdbms

I am trying to perform a simple insert query into a table in a Microsoft SQL Server database.

This table contains a `datetime` column named `TIMESTAMP` that have to contain the current date and the current time.

I am trying to do in this way but can't work:

```
INSERT INTO TirAliquotaRamoI (DataElaborazione, 
                              TassoLordoAnnuoAppl,
                              TassoGiornaliereNetto, 
                              Aliquota, 
                              DataInizio, 
                              DataFine, 
                              TIMESTAMP)
VALUES ('2015-08-01 00:00:00',
        0,
        0,
        1,
        '2015-08-01 00:00:00',
        '2100-12-32',
        TIMESTAMP);
```

It give me the following error message:

> 16:49:10  [INSERT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]
>   Error Code: 207, SQL State: S0001 
>   Invalid column name 'TIMESTAMP'.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: timestamp is a data type not a function that can be called. GETDATE() is what you're after.

Comment: be aware that `TIMESTAMP` is a SQL Server type that has **nothing** to do with time. Is just a poorly named alias for [`rowversion`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.110).aspx) which is an ever-increasing integer unrelated to time or date. The name `TIMESTAMP` has caused much confusion as users like you tend to associate it with date and time. Use [`GETUTCDATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx) for current time. And always store UTC in the database.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I would disagree that you should always store UTC values. There are plenty of situations where that isn't the best choice.

Comment: @SeanLange 3 words why you should stick to UTC: daylight saving time. When the changes kick in you experience all sort of anomalies like back in time travel, inversion of cause and effect and events that appear to duplicate, all because of DST. Me, I'll always stick with UTC. Can you name one reason why I should use DST in the DB, rather than convert time to local in display?

Comment: @RemusRusanu I don't want to get into a debate over what is right or wrong here. You have enough experience with sql server to know that the only absolute is "it depends". How about situations where you only care about the local time something happens and you aren't concerned about those strange anomalies? Do I personally use UTC? Yes, pretty much always because of the reasons you mentioned. Does that mean it is the only way that makes sense in every situation, of course not. And what about locations that don't observe DST?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are `insert`ing values in columns using `values`. So all of them have to be constant(s). They can't be column-names. Hence you get the error.

Change the query to insert `GETDATE()` (returns the current date with timestamp) into the TIMESTAMP column.

```
INSERT INTO TirAliquotaRamoI (DataElaborazione, 
                          TassoLordoAnnuoAppl,
                          TassoGiornaliereNetto, 
                          Aliquota, 
                          DataInizio, 
                          DataFine, 
                          TIMESTAMP)
VALUES ('2015-08-01 00:00:00',
    0,
    0,
    1,
    '2015-08-01 00:00:00',
    '2100-12-32',
    GETDATE());
```